# I think I am looking for a specific DC relay switch

Tags: switches, relay, dc

I am looking for a switch not sure what kind though.

let me explain:

I have two sources one creating DC 12v, second one creating around 6v DC.

One source works for about 12 hours each day then stops
the other works about 12 hours each day then stops. The next day this is all repeated.

During each 24 hour day one of these DCv sources is running a load.

What I am looking for is a switch that will automatically open the circuit "cut the circuit" of the DC 12v source that is NOT supplying power at that time, and keep the circuit closed for the one that is supplying power to the load. Then in about 12 hours later when the other DC 12v is ready it automatically opens the circuit of the DC 12v source that is NOT supplying power and so on.

First Source "this source will fluctuate from 12V to 6V
Right now I am getting the below amps at around 5 and a half V
310.2 ma
0.012 amps

Second Source "this source is my backup when the first one looses power" This source "the second source" always has a steady 12V
01.41 ma
0.141 amps

Hope this makes sense.

In summary, when one DC 12v is running the load I want the other ones circuit cut and vise versa.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. The textual description above is a bit convoluted, readers would find it much quicker to grasp your problem description if it were supported by a proposed schematic or at least a conceptual diagram for what you want to do.

Comment: Take a step back and instead of saying how you think the solution should be implemented, tell us what you want IT to do... "I need a load to be powered from one battery then when that battery is low I want it to be connected to an alternative battery". I've not mentioned 12 hours cycles because this may not be required for what you want. I may be wrong but hopefully this will spur you to think what you need in terms of functionality rather than solutions. I am a little confused by your question detail!!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? The source with the highest voltage will supply current to the load, while the other one is practically disconnected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNznkK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think the 6v source is the primary though.